# Do we delete some of the questions that have been closed?

Tags: discussion, deletion, closed-questions

There are at least seven pages of closed questions (I got the list by searching for `closed:1 the`).

Some of them are clearly off-topic and I believe we can delete them.

Here are a few:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045/how-do-i-write-math-equations-for-my-proffesor-closed

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482/inserting-chapters-into-a-latex-document-closed

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/is-it-possible-to-apply-brightness-and-contrast-on-an-image-using-raster-operatio

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/3d-modeling-vertex-resolution-closed

I believe we can also delete the ones closed as "Not a Real Question".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.  I agree that these add no value to the community.

Edit:  On the other hand, several closed questions have answers with positive vote totals.  If the questions are deleted, the answerers will lose the corresponding reputation.  Not a huge deal, but I was going to delete a whole bunch of closed questions until I realized this (still deleted a few, though).

Comment: Please consider deleting the "uses of "of"" question.

Answer (score 7):

My position on this is here

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/

Scroll down to "Why do you allow content to be deleted?" but the short version is, you should typically delete closed content *that adds no value to the community*.